# Flattens the nested array

Tags: if-statement

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    let newArr = [];

    arr.forEach(el => {
      if(Array.isArray(el)) {
        newArr.push(...steamrollArray(el));
      }
        newArr.push(el);  
    })
    return newArr; 
}

steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

It is supposed to log the output `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.
My question is why I have to put "else" after if-statement to make it work in the above code.
I do not know why else makes some difference.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without the `else` you would *always* append the original element to the result list, even a previously "steamrolled" sub-list. *With* the `else`, the original element is only added to the result list if it is not a list itself.

I did not test it, but I think without the `else` the result would thus be something like `[1, 2, [2], 3, 4, [4], [[4]], [3, [[4]]]]`